# Moving to matching braces in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, parentheses, curly-braces

I have several R functions which I am scripting in RStudio. These functions are quite long. Is there a keyboard shortcut to skip from an opening brace to a closing brace in RStudio so I can more efficiently run these functions without having to scroll the script file?

Comment: use ctrl+p. u can check the keyboard shortcuts in the menu bar -> tools

Comment: @chinsoon12 is there a way to jump backwards to the opening bracket? I can't see one in the list of shortcuts, thanks

Comment: i think it works backwards as well...just place the cursor on the left of the closing bracket

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use `Ctrl+p` to navigate to the closing brace/parenthesis.

You can also check the keyboard shortcuts in the Menu bar -> Tools -> Modify Keyboard Shortcuts.

Or from https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts

> Jump to Matching Brace/Paren  Ctrl+P

Answer (score 0):

In the RStudio v1.4 [preview](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/09/30/rstudio-v1-4-preview-visual-markdown-editing/) there is matching parentheses, braces, and brackets in a series of colors. This is customizable in the theme CSS. It can also be turned on/off dynamically per document through the `Code -> Rainbow parentheses option.` See [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/7027).

[image]